# How can I add gradle project dependencies without modifying settings.gradle

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

### Background

(Please keep in mind I've simplified the problem for purposes of discussion here)

- I've got a set of applications and dependent libraries, something like this (each with a `src/` directory and `build.gradle`):

  ```
  appa/
  appb/
  libx/
  liby/
  libz/
  ```
- In `build.gradle`, the dependencies are currently declared like this:

  ```
  appa/build.gradle:
     compile "com.asdf:libx:1.0"
     compile "com.asdf:liby:1.0"
  appb/build.gradle:
     compile "com.asdf:liby:1.0"
  liby/build.gradle:
     compile "com.asdf:libz:1.0"
  ```

### What problem am I trying to solve

- Say I'm working on `appa`, and I need to make changes to `libx`.  I need to do multiple steps:

  1. Pull `libx` from source control and make changes locally
  2. Rebuild and push changes to some repo (not prod!)
  3. Rebuild `appa` (pulling the recently updated `libx` from repo)
- If my testing reveals a bug in `libx`, I've got to repeat that over again.
- This is super-annoying when working in IDEs like Eclipse, where even though my projects are logically using other projects, I've got to still use the artifacts as dependencies.
- Wouldn't it be great if I can just pull the project locally, and projects that logically depend on it will automatically use the source project instead of artifact for building?

### What I've done so far

- I've written a small gradle plugin (referenced in each project's `build.gradle`) that identifies `com.asdf` dependencies, and uses [dependency substitution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html) to replace the artifact dependency with a project dependency if that project exists locally.

  ```
  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
          all { DependencySubstitution dependency ->
              if (dependency.requested instanceof ModuleComponentSelector && dependency.requested.group == 'com.asdf') {
                  def targetProject = findProject(":${dependency.requested.module}")
                  if (targetProject != null) {
                      dependency.useTarget targetProject
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Yay! With a few modifications to `settings.gradle` (see below), I've accomplished my goal... Except...

### Where I'm stuck

- I need to modify `settings.gradle` to include lines like this for every dependency (otherwise `findProject` doesn't resolve the dependent project during build):

  ```
  include ':libx'
  project(':libx').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../libx')
  ```
- While it's *possible* to go through all the `settings.gradle` files and do this (I've done it for a handful as my proof-of-concept), it's ugly, repetitive, and is logically the same information that is being passed to `compile` arguments for the `build.gradle` dependencies.

  - It's also error-prone when someone adds a new dependency but doesn't update `settings.gradle`, or introduces a typo between them.
- I've also tried making `settings.gradle` just define projects for all directories it finds at that level, but then building any project turns into a mega-build of all projects.
- (I've tried several other things, but my question is getting long in the tooth already)

### My question

What's a better way to do this, without duplicating information between `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle`?  I want to make it so adding new dependencies is still just as easy as adding the `compile` reference in `build.gradle`, without touching `settings.gradle`...

I'm still rather new to groovy/gradle, so maybe I'm missing something that's obvious to the more experienced gradle master?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)

Comment: @mkobit - that definitely looks promising on the surface. Will take a deeper look after the weekend and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your use-case is the motivation for [Composite Builds](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-composite-builds).

I have a demo [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_Composite_Build), which writes to a `jars` folder as a mock publishing of artifacts. Be sure to check-out the README.md as the demo is a mini-laboratory for trying out the use-case before and after composite builds.

In the demo `mainBuild` is `appa`; `utils` is `libx`. The key syntax in `mainBuild/settings.gradle` ([here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/blob/master/egg_Composite_Build/mainBuild/settings.gradle)) is:

```
includeBuild '../utils'
```

This tells Gradle to use the local codebase instead of the published artifact. Of course, one would not commit this line to source-control.

Comment: Definitely useful, but there seem to be some limitations to composite builds - based on the doc, they can only go one level deep (can't depend on another composite build), and it still requires duplicating info in `settings.gradle` (though it looks like "less" mucking, it's still needed).  Definitely an area worth exploring further though, thanks :)